# Всплывающие подсказки Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Долго ползал по интернету в поисках инструкции по включению расширенных всплывающих подсказок для Visual Studio. По типу вот таких:
[image: Вот такие подсказки нужны]

У меня же в Visual Studio 2022 они выглядят вот так:

[image: вот такие вот у меня]

Мне нужно, чтобы выводилась сводка с описанием того, что делает функция/поле/конструктор.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это описание пишется в конструкции

```
 /// <summary>
 ///
 /// </summary>
```

Скриншот приложил. Дело тут не в настройках студии, что она что-то не показывает. Если разработчик к методу не оставил описания, то вы ничего и не увидите.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст ответа можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, такой функциональностью раньше очень хорошо обладал [решарпер](https://www.jetbrains.com/ru-ru/resharper/). Это - вообще мощная штука, но требующая внимания и изучения.

Если с решарпером возиться неохота - можно попробовать [Codist](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wmj.Codist) . я его не пробовал, но функционал заявлен похожий - можете потом поделиться впечатлениями в коментариях.

А можно делать так, как наши отцы и деды - выделять функцию и жмакать F1. Правда, будет не popup, а целая страница в браузере, зато работает сразу.

Comment: Неужели это делается только через расширения? Даже в  руководстве по IntelliSense есть такая штука
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/using-intellisense?view=vs-2022
(скриншот под заголовком "Сведения о параметрах").

Comment: В общем, никакого противоремя тут нет. я проверил - про DateTime у меня показывается ровно то же самое, что и у Вас. Выше там еще один человек оставил второй ответ, который рассказывает, "откуда всё это берется". Так что у Вас включены те самые "расширенные подсказки" - просто демонстрировать их на примере DateTime() не получится - место неудачное :-)