# Всплывающие подсказки Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio

В общем задавал я пару дней назад [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1387934/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-visual-studio/1387972?noredirect=1#comment2467233_1387972), касательно всплывающих подсказок в визуалке. Мне там дали ответ, как оно работает, и я успокоился.
Но посмотрев пару видосов по C# на ютубе я увидел, что у людей-то всплывающие подсказки есть. И работают они нормально.
Решил проверить, как вообще сделаны описания в C# и вот что я там увидел:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
То есть описание сделано через обычный комментарий, а не через:

```
///<summary>
///
///</summary>
```

Собственно, поэтому и подсказки не выводятся.
Если подписать свой метод через `<summary>`, то будет выводиться полная всплывающая подсказка с тем, что я туда ввёл.
Что с этим поделать можно? всё-таки хотелось бы видеть подсказки, а то каждый раз нажимать <kbd>F12</kbd> или <kbd>F1</kbd>, чтобы прочесть, что значат параметры или просто сам метод не очень-то хочется, когда знаешь, что есть более удобный способ.

Если что, у меня **VS2022**.

**UPD:**
Создал `консольное приложение` - попробовал там это сделать и всё заработало:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Зашёл обратно в проект `WinForms`, а там  уже не работает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И как это работает - понять не могу. Хочу заставить это работать именно в WinForms...

Comment: То, что у вас на скрине - результат работы декомпилятора, который подставил описание как комментарий в декомпилированный код. В оригинальном коде точно нет комментария на русском: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src%2Flibraries%2FSystem.Private.CoreLib%2Fsrc%2FSystem%2FDateTime.cs

Comment: ага... понял, но ещё прикол в том, что описание из декомпилированного кода совпадают с описаниями, которые высвечиваются в подсказках в любом видео по C#....

Comment: Ну так естественно совпадают - у подсказок и у описания декомпилятора общий источник.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создал проект на более новых версиях .NET - как я понял, это работает с версии **`.NET 4.8`**, по крайней мере в **`Visual Studio 2022`**.